# Existence of isometry that aligns same length vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, isometry

Let $A,B,C,D$ be four points in $\Bbb R^n$ with $dist(A,B)=dist(C,D)$. Prove that there exists an isometry $f$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $f(A)=C$ and $f(B)=D$.

---

I want to use the fact that each isometry is of the form $f = Mx + n$ where $M$ is an orthogonal matrix. Intuitively, $f$ rotates the vector defined by $A,B$ and then translates it so it is aligned with the vector defined with $C,D$. Any ideas how can I formalize it into a proof?

Answer (score 1):

You could express your intuitive idea as follows:

Let $t$ be the translation mapping $A$ to $C$. Then $t(B)$ and $D$ are equidistant from $C$. Therefore there is a rotation $r$, centre $C$, mapping $t(B)$ to $D$.

Then $rt(A)=r(C)=C$ and  $rt(B)=D$, as required.

ADDED EXPLANATION

If we translate by $a$ (to the origin), multiply by an orthogonal matrix $M$ and then translate by $b$, these transformations do the following to any point v.

$M(v+a)+b=M(v)+M(a)+b$ and $Ma+b$ is your $n$.

Comment: Why is $rt$ of the form mentioned above?

Comment: The simple answer is because it is obviously an isometry. The slightly more difficult question is why do all isometries have the form you give - but you appear to already know that.

Comment: Maybe what I'm missing is the definition of "rotation" in $\Bbb R^n$, and why it is necessarily an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: A rotation about any particular point can be thought of as a combination of translations and a rotation about the origin. The rotation about the origin  is an isometry which preserves dot products and can therefore be represented by an orthogonal matrix. (As can a reflection about a line through the origin.)

Comment: I've added an explanation of why there's no problem about shifting things to the origin to use an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the only thing that still bothers me is why if $t(B)$ and $D$ are equidistant from $C$, then there is an orthogonal transformation $r$ like you mentioned. It is probably elementary, but it's been a while since I've studied linear algebra.

Comment: Does it help to consider the rotation matrix $\begin{pmatrix}cos A&sinA\\-sinA&cosA\\\end{pmatrix}$ which rotates however much we want and is clearly orthogonal?

Comment: How would you generalize it to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: I would take x,y axes in the plane which I was rotating (the plane of t(B),C,D in my original answer) and then the matrix is effectively just this one. You can have $1$ s on the diagonal for any other dimensions.